# Set condition in struts for CSS

Tags: css, struts

I have a table in my HTML page and I want set different style for header, even and odd rows in table.
My page write with JSP , struts and HTML and use "iterator" in struts to create table rows.
Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everybody!

I found my answer: http://www.vaannila.com/struts-2/struts-2-example/struts-2-iterator-tag-example1.html

Answer (score 2):

In your loop for generating the table, alternate a class for the `<tr>` tag..

e.g.

```
<tr class="odd">
<tr class="even">
<tr class="odd">
etc..
```

Then in CSS do

```
tr.odd { background: red; }
td.even { background: blue; }
```

Comment: Please explain on it:<s:iterator value="personList"><tr><td>sth</td>...<td>sth</td></tr></s:iterator>